# Why i cant add "\n" in c++ cout statement . and what is

Tags: c++

On the last line in the code below, the compiler give me an error on the `"\n"`:

> ERROR expected ';' before string constant

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1;
    double num2;
    cout << "enter the inetger: \n";
    cin>>num1;
    cout<<"enter the float: \n";
    cin>>num2;
    cout<<"integer:""\t"<<num1<<" and float:""\t"<<num2"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an Image:

[image]

Comment: Check your syntax very carefully.

Comment: You just forgot the `<<` between `num2` and `"\n"`. This question is probably just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use << to concatenate like

```
cout<<"integer:""\t"<<num1<<" and float:""\t"<<num2<<"\n";
```

or better use

```
cout<<"integer:""\t"<<num1<<" and float:""\t"<<num2<<endl;
```

Comment: endl is not necessarily better as it force flush the stream.

Comment: not so obvious where you did add the `<<`, btw you didnt have to put one in between here: `"integer:""\t"`

Comment: yes right, also the "" inside causes error

Comment: @idclev463035818 The compiler concatenates string literals separated by whitespace (even CR/LF), so "a" "bc" "def" becomes "abcdef".

Comment: ok now i understand . but what is force flush stream .

Comment: @franji1 I know, but thats not my point. OP probably doesn't. And I suppose if I didnt know then this question would confuse me

Comment: @idclev463035818 sry for the inconvenience . i am actually start learning C++ . so i don't know about those things . btw thank you for the help .

Comment: @inoobbe "*i am actually start learning C++ . so i don't know about those things*" - then get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that covers these things.